# How to echo date parts separately

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, date

I have found place online where they answer different things, but I still don't get how I can apply it to my code.

Basically I want the month in one echo-line, and the day-number in another echo.

Is there away to do that in my code?

```
  <?php 
  // Connects to your Database 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, description, location, date FROM Calendar") 
  or die(mysql_error());  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  { 

  echo "<article>";
  echo "<date>"; 
  echo "<h3>" .$row['date(month)'] . "</h3>";
  echo "<h4>" .$row['date(day)'] . "</h4>"; 
  echo "</date>";

  echo "</article>";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get them ahead of time in your MySQL query, as an alternative to parsing them out later in PHP.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, description, location, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m') AS `month`, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d') AS `day` FROM Calendar") 
  or die(mysql_error());
```

Then to access them:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
   echo $row['month'];
   echo $row['day'];
}
```

Alternatively to get the month's name instead of number, use `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') as month`

[MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i wanted. what would i add to only get the first 3 characters of the %M name?? Thanks

Comment: @MaltheMilthers See the documentation link.  Abbreviated month name is `%b`

Comment: Thanks alot - dont know why i didnt find that. much appriciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just pass the date straight through strtotime:

```
$month = date('m', strtotime($row['date']));
$day = date('d', strtotime($row['date']));
```

But this will depend on the format the date is stored in the database. This should work for a `TIMESTAMP` type column or a UNIX timestamp, or (for the most part) a string representation of a date.

Answer (score 0):

You first get the unix time of the date and then format two different strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo date as exactly the name of the month, you can use 'F'.
Like this:

$month = date('F', strtotime($row['dateRepaired']));